# mail shows Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com when site is not hosted in main domain

Tags: laravel, ssl, smtp, gmail

i am trying to send mail using laravel. it works fine in localhost. but gives an error as below
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Network is unreachable)

But here to mention. my site is hosted in mysite.com/citizen. so i checked it with a site with main domain like anothersite.com and now it works fine. i think i have a path problem. i am trying to find the solution but not beign able to find it anywhere, anybody please help...

here is my env configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

i have tried changing the driver into sendmail but in this case gmail says its phishing and asks to report the mail

Comment: you need to add your website to the allowed devices, there are a lot of guides on the web that tells you step by step how to do it

Comment: where i have to add it in allowed devices.??...can u explain more.?

Comment: @Berto99: This is about not being able to connect and not being able to authenticate. Your advice is for authentication problems, not connectivity problems.

Comment: is there a 2fa in your google account?

Answer (score 1):

> .. my site is hosted in mysite.com/citizen. so i checked it with a site with main domain like anothersite.com and now it works fine. i think i have a path problem.

The path of your site does not matter at all. Instead there is probably a firewall which disallows connections to the mail server port 465 on the hosting service for `mysite.com` but there is no such firewall on the hosting service for `anothersite.com`. This is indicated by `Network is unreachable`, i.e. it cannot even establish a TCP connection to the mail server.

There is not much you can do about this. Check with your hosting provider of why this port is blocked and what alternative ways they propose.

Comment: you sure that i dont have anything to do,? like from my point of view as a developer.? then i will inform others responsible about this to solve the issue